# is .net copying data or pointing to it

Tags: c#

little query re: how .net works with system memory..

i pass a list object to a method:

```
DoMyThing(myListObj);

public void DoMyThing(List<string> myListObj)
{
    var a = myListObj;
}
```

in this scenario, is `a` a 'copy' of, or a pointer to the myListObj?

to make this slightly different... here a dictionary say (assume of single item), and 'pick' something out of that object, does that copy data, or point to it?

```
DoMyThing(myDictObj);

public void DoMyThing(Dictionary<string, string> myDictObj)
{
    var b = myDictObj.First().Value;
}
```

ultimate goal here is trying to make some of my code a bit more memory optimal.. there are situations where an object i send to a method can be ~100mb

thanks!

Comment: `a` is pointing to the same object as `myListObj`. You can test this for yourself by `Add`ing an entry to it and seeing that the other object has the same new entry.

Comment: In your samples, you are passing these values by reference. You should read about the data types and if they are value types (int, boolean, etc) or not.

Comment: `and 'pick' something out of that object, does that copy data, or point to it?` It will be pointing to the same string. If it was a value type, it would copy it instead.

Comment: Also, the way to optimize memory usage is to use a profiler. Not take wild stabs at things that "might" be using memory.

Comment: Careful about what "pointer" means to you though.  `a` cannot be dereferenced; if you assign a new value to it the entry in `myListObj` doesn't change.  If you want to modify an object assigned to `a` then reference vs. value type comes into play.